# How to let people do cname to my domain?

Tags: dns, cname

I have a regular webpage (my-page.com) and want people to be able to do a cname (hi.their-domain.com) to that page.

But if I create a cname record for hi.their-domain.com to point to my-page.com it responds with "500 Internal Server Error".

I thought that I could do a cname to whatever domain I wanted to but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Back to my question, how can I let people create a cname record from their domain to mine?

Comment: 500 internal server error may mean something else. look at your error logs.

Comment: The same thing happens if I try to add a cname to:
test.my-domain.com CNAME to www.apple.com

So are you sure that I don't have to enable something at my own server since I'm not able to do a cname to apple either?